# How to rebuild ethereum block hash using Solidity/JavaScript

Tags: solidity, javascript, hash, blockhash

Can someone point me to a good resource to see how a BLOCK HASH is being built by hashing the BLOCK HEADER fields (which fields and how to process/encode them - keccak/rlp)?

My main goal is to get the block data from 'eth_getBlockByHash' RPC call and send all of the pieces to Solidity so that there to process the pieces and rebuild the hash and compare the hash with the block hash coming from the RPC call.

It would be great if it's written in Solidity but something like JavaScript would also be beneficial so I can then translate it to Solidity.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This works (disclaimer, it was written by GPT-4, not by me. There probably are better, cleaner approaches to doing that, but i tested it and it works perfectly)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { rlp, toBuffer } = require('ethereumjs-util');
const { keccak256 } = require('js-sha3');

const rpc_url = 'YOUR_RPC_URL';

async function getBlockData(blockNumber) {
    const payload = {
        jsonrpc: '2.0',
        method: 'eth_getBlockByNumber',
        params: ['0x' + blockNumber.toString(16), false],
        id: 1
    };

    const response = await axios.post(rpc_url, payload);
    return response.data.result;
}

async function getBlockHash(blockNumber) {
    const blockData = await getBlockData(blockNumber);

    const blockHeader = [
        toBuffer(blockData.parentHash),
        toBuffer(blockData.sha3Uncles),
        toBuffer(blockData.miner),
        toBuffer(blockData.stateRoot),
        toBuffer(blockData.transactionsRoot),
        toBuffer(blockData.receiptsRoot),
        toBuffer(blockData.logsBloom),
        toBuffer(parseInt(blockData.difficulty.slice(2), 16)),
        toBuffer(parseInt(blockData.number.slice(2), 16)),
        toBuffer(parseInt(blockData.gasLimit.slice(2), 16)),
        toBuffer(parseInt(blockData.gasUsed.slice(2), 16)),
        toBuffer(parseInt(blockData.timestamp.slice(2), 16)),
        toBuffer(blockData.extraData),
        toBuffer(blockData.mixHash),
        toBuffer(blockData.nonce)
    ];
    
    const encodedBlockHeader = rlp.encode(blockHeader);
    const blockHash = keccak256(encodedBlockHeader);

    return '0x' + blockHash;
}

async function main() {
    const blockNumber = 12345678;
    const rpcBlockHash = (await getBlockData(blockNumber)).hash;
    const computedBlockHash = await getBlockHash(blockNumber);
    const hashMatch = computedBlockHash === rpcBlockHash;

    console.log(`Computed Block Hash: ${computedBlockHash}`);
    console.log(`RPC Block Hash: ${rpcBlockHash}`);
    console.log(`Hash Match: ${hashMatch}`);
}

main();
```

Note that you really should *not* be doing that in solidity, at least in a production setting. It's expensive and completely useless. Do that off-chain, and verify the result on-chain, if you really need to.